# Bundler errors in environment with Rails 3.1 gem installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I've got Rails 3.0.10 and 3.1 installed because I am trying to use both for two different projects.

In my Rails 3.0.10 project, I have the following at the top of my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.10'
```

However, after running `bundle install; bundle exec rails --version`, I'm getting the following:

```
/Users/bradley/.rbenv/versions/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `setup': You have already activated activesupport 3.1.1, but your Gemfile requires activesupport 3.0.10. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/bradley/.rbenv/versions/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:17:in `setup'
    from /Users/bradley/.rbenv/versions/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:110:in `setup'
    from /Users/bradley/.rbenv/versions/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/cli.rb:340:in `exec'
    from /Users/bradley/.rbenv/versions/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
    from /Users/bradley/.rbenv/versions/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/bradley/.rbenv/versions/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /Users/bradley/.rbenv/versions/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/bradley/.rbenv/versions/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
    from /Users/bradley/.rbenv/versions/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/bin/bundle:13
    from /Users/bradley/.rbenv/versions/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /Users/bradley/.rbenv/versions/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/bin/bundle:19
```

Any ideas? Obviously, I'm already using `bundle exec` and `bundle show rails; bundle show activesupport` confirm that I should be using the right versions of the gems. Do I just need to uninstall Rails 3.1?

Comment: Are you try write in Gemfile `gem 'activesupport', '3.0.10'`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that too. It's still trying to load 3.1 for some reason.

Comment: Can you add the contents of you Gemfile? It's possible that one of your gems depends on activesupport and is pulling in version 3.1.1

Comment: Sure, here's the [`Gemfile`](http://pastie.org/private/rkftabpodzcwzk4b5s4gw) and [`Gemfile.lock`](http://pastie.org/private/5t5keqo1fzsyc9tsgekra)

Comment: Any ideas? I tried manually changing all the references to `active support` and `activesupport (>= 2.3.x)` in my Gemfile.lock to be `(~> 3.0.10)` but it didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 3):

I've run into the same problem.

***Even when I explicitly specify the version of activesupport to use*** in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.9'
gem 'activesupport', '3.2.9'
```

it still gives me this error when I run `bundle exec rails s`:

```
/home/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup':
You have already activated activesupport 3.2.10, but your Gemfile requires activesupport 3.2.9. Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError)
```

This happens for me when I want to try going back to an older version of Rails in my app to test a difference between the two versions of Rails.

So even creating a separate gemset for my app (which we usually do anyway) does not solve the problem, because the gemset was "polluted" by this app itself (by temporarily installing/using Rails 3.2.10 before going back to Rails 3.2.9), not by some other app!

**The only solution I've found so far** is to **uninstall** the newer version that you don't want it to use:

```
gem uninstall activesupport -v 3.2.10
```

It seems like this is either a bug in Bundler or a bug in Rails (if it does something that causes activesupport to be loaded/activated *before* it loads Bundler, then we can't really blame it on Bundler...).

**Another equally terrible solution:** To disable a newer version of a gem *temporarily* **without uninstalling** it, you can edit the gem's specification file (for example, `/home/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/specifications/activesupport-3.2.10.gemspec`) and add a line `raise 'disabled'` at the top. Bundler will skip the loading of `activesupport 3.2.10` (after rescuing and printing the error) and proceed to load the next highest version of `activesupport` that it can find (`activesupport 3.2.9`).

When you're ready to re-enable `activesupport 3.2.10`, simply remove the `raise`.

This may be quicker than uninstalling and reinstalling a gem, if you just want to test something with the older version before going back to the newer version of them gem.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I thought I was the only one. I'm leaning towards a Rails bug as it seems to be happening before bundler is loaded.

Comment: This happened to me again today. I needed to go back in time using git (check out an earlier version of my app) to try to track down a regression, and of course I'd upgraded activesupport since then, so I had to gem uninstall activesupport -v 3.1.3 before I could even get cucumber to run. // I'm leaning towards a Rails bug too. I wish bundler gave a better error telling you *where*/*how* the newer version got activated. "You have already activated activesupport 3.1.3 here: [full backtrace showing what triggered to be activated]" Then we could instantly know which line in Rails was problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my gem file, I changed the rails version to my current version:

gem 'rails', '3.2.2'

I executed the command: bundle update

And the error goes away

Answer (score 0):

Create a '.rvmrc' file in each RAILS_ROOT dir (so at the root of each project)

fill it with:

```
vm_install_on_use_flag=1
rvm_gemset_create_on_use_flag=1
rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p290@APPNAME
```

where APPNAME is different for each app. CD out of the app dir and then back in. When you CD in, say yes to trusting the gem set. Then run Bundle install in each.

You created 2 gemsets, one for each project, so there is no cross-pollination of apps. This should fix the issues.

Comment: I just switched away from RVM to RBEnv. I thought the whole point of bundler was to avoid creating things like gem sets.

Comment: No, using them together creates isolated environments for your apps. gemsets are a good thing to have: http://bcardarella.com/post/699582642/rvm-gemsets-bundler-awesome

Comment: But if the point of bundler is to load the appropriate gem dependencies for my project, why would I need a gem set? I definitely understand using rvm or rbenv for managing different ruby versions. Just seems like Bundler should load the correct version of activesupport for my version of rails.

Comment: It should.... but then there are gems that specify a version greater than 2 of another gem., which at the time was fine, but now version 4 is incompatible. So you have 2 and 4 on your system, but don't explicitly say you want to load 2.

Comment: Bundler loads the gems into the gemset/environment... it doesn't tell your app what ones to use specifically. Sometimes, if you don't explicitly say you want to use a certain version, the latest version found on the system is generally used.

Comment: Shouldn't adding `gem 'activesupport', '3.0.10'` to my Gemfile take care of that? I tried that and it's still loading 3.1.1 first. I'm thinking this a bundler/rails3 bug but I'm not sure.

Comment: Did you try making a new gem set? Just wondering, that would isolate this issue and then you can blame bundler/rails3/me/the president

Comment: Sorry, I have not. I've used rvm and gemsets in the past and I believe you're right that this would fix the problem. I appreciate your suggestion. I'm kind of committed to using rbenv at this point, and I'm more just trying to understand how Bundler is handling this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4849/discussion-between-bradley-and-jared)

Answer (score 0):

This may be off point, but **please** use Ruby Version Manager (RVM).

It will allow you to manage multiple ruby version installations as well as what is called **gemsets** which allow you to maintain global repos for all your gems (diff versions for each gem as well) and set which one you wish to use at any given time.

Aside from all that, look at cleaning up your installed gems and starting fresh:

```
gem clean -d # dry mode will simply tell you what will get cleaned

gem clean -v # will remove all older versions of every single gem
```

Other than that you can force remove the rails gem along with its dependencies (you can check what dependencies your rails version has)

```
gem uninstall actionmailer actionpack activerecord activesupport acriveresource rails -v=3.1.0
```

Hope that helps. Cheers!